# topical vs thematic

Tags: difference

One of the meanings of "topical" from [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/topical):

> relating to a particular subject; classified according to subject:
>
> *topical categories / descriptors / menus / interest / themes / arrangement / collection*

One of the meanings of "thematic" from [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/thematic):

> having or relating to subjects or a particular subject:
>
> *thematic orientation / chapters / essay / organization / subjects / studies / analysis / questions / focus / areas / shows / principle / lines / undercurrent / consistency / connections*

What's the difference between these meanings? They seem to me the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you have correctly spotted, these two words have the same meaning *in this sense*. They are pretty much perfect literal substitutes for one another if you are talking about 'classification according to subject.'

Nevertheless, because they are different words, and not identical in *all senses*, they have different connotations.

The first and probably most important distinction is that in some cases *thematic* is used in the UK and *topical* in the US: for example, a UK stamp collector might call part of their collection dealing with some subject a *thematic collection* while a US collector would call it a *topical collection*.

The second and much harder to define difference comes from the difference in the root words. As you can probably tell from their spelling, *topical* is to *topic* as *thematic* is to *theme*. *Theme* carries with it a more official connotation; one of essays in school; or a musical meaning. *Topic* carries a more informal, conversational connotation. Thus *topical* often describes everyday items like menus and arrangements, while *thematic* often describes more learned subjects like chapters, essays, studies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the meanings of "topical" and "thematic"  fo overlap in the area of "categorizing thiungs" but that is no9t the primary sense of either word. "topical" most often means "current" or "present day" as in "about a current **topic**". One might say:

> This 1963 novel about a trip to the Moon was very topical when it came out, but now it is a period-piece.

As for "thematic", I understand that the sorting sense is almost exclusively British in use. In the US one would never say "a thematic collection". [Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thematic) gives the first sense as:

> of, relating to, or constituting a theme

so one might say of a novel

> The plot-arc about the journey over the glacier is thematic.

meaning that it advances or is part of the theme of the book, while some other aspect of the plot does (or is) not. [I am thinking here of *The Left Hand of Darkness* by Le Guin.] One might also use "the4matic" of a work devoted to a particualtr theme, as opposed to one entertainign, but not really having a distinct theme.

The senses of the two words that are very similar may still be affected by their other differign sense.